# LINQ to Entities combine two IQueryable<AnonymousType>

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 queries which work fine:

```
var  q = (from c in _context.Wxlogs

                where (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", c.LogDate2) == m3) && (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Year", c.LogDate2) == y1)
                group c by c.LogDate2
                into g
                orderby g.Key
                let maxTemp = g.Max(c => c.Temp)
                let minTemp = g.Min(c => c.Temp)
                let maxHum = g.Max(c => c.Humidity)
                let minHum = g.Min(c => c.Humidity)

                select new 
                           {
                               LogDate = g.Key,
                               MaxTemp = maxTemp,
                               MaxTempTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Temp == maxTemp).LogTime,
                               MinTemp = minTemp,
                               MinTempTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Temp == minTemp).LogTime,
                               MaxHum = maxHum,
                               MaxHumTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Humidity == maxHum).LogTime,
                               MinHum = minHum,
                               MinHumTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Humidity == minHum).LogTime,
                           });

var  r = (from c in _context.Wxlogs
                where
                    (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", c.LogDate2) == m3) &&
                    (SqlFunctions.DatePart("Year", c.LogDate2) == y1)
                group c by c.LogDate2
                    into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    let maxDew = g.Max(c => c.Dew_Point)
                    let minDew = g.Min(c => c.Dew_Point)
                    //let maxWind = g.Max(c=> c.Wind_Gust)
                    let maxRainRate = g.Max(c => c.Rain_rate_now)
                    let maxPres = g.Max(c => c.Barometer)
                    let minPres = g.Min(c => c.Barometer)

                    select new
                               {
                                   LogDate = g.Key,
                                   MaxRainRateTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Rain_rate_now == maxRainRate).LogTime,
                                   MaxPres = maxPres,
                                   MaxPresTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Barometer == maxPres).LogTime,
                                   MinPres = minPres,
                                   MinPresTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Barometer == minPres).LogTime,
                                   MinDew = minDew,
                                   MinDewTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Dew_Point == minDew).LogTime,
                                   MaxDew = maxDew,
                                   MaxDewTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Dew_Point == maxDew).LogTime,
                                   MaxRainRate = maxRainRate,

                               });
```

however when I try to combine them using union, in order to output the results to a WPF datgrid:

```
var result = r.Union(q);
```

the following error is thrown on the union:

```
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'
```

I can't seem to find a way to make this work and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since a union operation doesn't make sense here, can you explain exactly what you're expecting to get out of your code?

Comment: I originally had this as one long query, which passed the results via ToList() to a WPF datagrid.  However I continually got OutofMemory exception errors, until the query was split.

Comment: Wait a second here. Are you actually trying to do a `join` operation?

Comment: I might be :-)  sort of new to LINQ.  Had looked at Join, but thought that was only to join tables into a query.

Comment: If you're trying to get the results of two queries next to each other, you want a `join`; if you want the results of the two queries to be in top and bottom sets of rows in your data grid, you want a `concat`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.  Will work on doing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "union" operation combines two sequences of the *same* type into a single set (i.e. eliminating all the duplicates). Since you clearly have sequences of two different types, you don't want a union operation. It looks like you want a "concat" operation, which just chains two sequences together. You need something like:

```
var result = r.Concat<object>(q);
```

However, since you're using L2E, your query will try to get executed on the server. Since your server won't allow you to combine your two queries (due to mismatched types), you need to execute them separately and then concat the sequences on the client:

```
var result = r.AsEnumerable().Concat<object>(q.AsEnumerable());
```

The use of `AsEnumerable()` runs the queries on the server and brings the results to the client.

Since it turns out that you want to combine the sequences next to each other (i.e. using the same rows in your grid but another group of columns), you actually want a `join` operation:

```
var result = from rrow in r.AsEnumerable()
             join qrow in q.AsEnumerable() on rrow.LogDate equals qrow.LogDate
             select new { rrow.LogDate,
                          rrow.MaxTemp, rrow.MaxTempTime,
                          rrow.MinTemp, rrow.MinTempTime,
                          rrow.MaxHum, rrow.MaxHumTime,
                          rrow.MinHum, rrow.MinHumTime,
                          qrow.MaxRainRate, qrow.MaxRainRateTime,
                          qrow.MaxPres, qrow.MaxPresTime,
                          qrow.MinPres, qrow.MinPresTime,
                          qrow.MaxDew, qrow.MaxDewTime,
                          qrow.MinDew, qrow.MinDewTime };
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried Concat but got the same error as stated above.  Your answer compiles but an error is thrown at runtime.     Message=DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes

Comment: That works thanks, however am getting 2 separate lists now, which are joined.  e.g. I'm getting the dates twice, once with the first set of data then once with the second set of data.  The aim was to get the dates once with all the data.

Comment: Thanks!  that's brilliant & works perfectly (just had to swap rrow and qrow around).